# Audio: bit depth reduction in software

Tags: audio, bit-depth

How does one reduce the bit depth of an audio file? Is it ignoring the MSBs or the LSBs? Mixture of both? (Side question: what is this called?)

Answer (score 1):

*TL/DR*: right shift the audio curve height variable to lower bit depth

audio can be thought of as an analog curve of amplitude (Y axis) over time (X axis). To digitize this curve (recording process) somehow the curve needs to get stored as bytes of storage (CD/DVD/hard-drive) which can recreate the curve on playback.  Typically the curve is sampled (measured) N times per second (44.1k hertz) This determines sample rate (higher the better).  For each sample of the audio curve the only attribute recorded is curve height (Y axis).  The resolution (fidelity) of this sample value is your bit depth.  Lets say after we normalize the analog audio curve this Y axis can only ever vary from 0 to 1

```
 1 bit of storage can only record two (2^1) values : either 0 or 1
 2 bits can store four (2^2) possible values: 0, 0.33, 0.66, 1.0
 3 bits (2^3) can store 8 possible values: 0 to 1 with increments of 1/8th
 8 bits (2^8) maps to 256 values:          0 to 1 increments of 1/256
16 bits maps to 65536 possible values:     0 to 1 with increments of 1/65536
```

so to convert bit depth from higher to lower you can see this would reduce the fidelity of your audio curve (making the curve jagged not smooth) since it reduces the number of possible (Y axis) curve height values.  It follows that this bit depth reduction can be thought of as shifting bits to the right (dropping off the LSB side)  (Sign-propagating right shift)

To maximize efficiency (audio quality per storage required) whenever you wish to reduce bit depth you would also reduce sample rate ... to keep things balanced ... otherwise when you reduce the bit depth you would be consuming too much storage using too high a sample rate ... to be explicit when you lower bit depth and fail to also reduce sample rate you will be generating successive audio sample values with identical Y axis values even though your actual audio curve is changing over time yet changing too slow to matter across multiple samples

Answer (score 0):

Bit depth reduction is good for sound synthesis in electronic music.

You can encode a music file to 1 bit,  but u dont play it back absolutely, you play it back as going louder and softer, as a derivative,  and it actually compresses as good as mp3! (~10%)

And it actually sounds pretty nice.